# Cross-User Testing using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I want to test Test My applications with different Users parallely in my applications.

Is it possible to achieve the same using selenium ?
If yes, How achieve the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use multiple driver instances, driver1 = user1, driver2 = user2.

Where driver1 = new RemoteWebDriver(hubURL, settings1);
and driver2 = new RemoteWebDriver(hubURL, settings2);